# Imaged loaded via new WWW doesn't display in a build, but it does in the player

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm loading a .jpeg file in at runtime from disk, it works absolutely fine in the player but when I build the project the texture being loaded in via WWW doesn't display - no errors. It suggests a format issue, but like I said it renders as expected in the player:

Unit doc: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture.html

```
        private IEnumerator SetMaterialImage(string path)
        {
        Texture2D tex;
        tex = new Texture2D(4, 4, TextureFormat.RGB24, false, true);
        WWW www = new WWW(path);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        {
            Debug.Log("ERROR REDNERING IMAGE --- " + www.error);
        }

        while (!www.isDone) yield return null;

        if (www.isDone)
        {
            Debug.Log("WWW,ISDONE = TRUE");
            Shader shader = Shader.Find("Standard");
            www.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.shader = shader;
        }
    }
```

Edit: please don't suggest the Resources folder - this particular application must load from disk

Comment: You left so many things required to help you out. Where are you running this? What is the value of the 'path' variable?  Use Debug.Log to print that then make sure that it actually exist.

Comment: 'it works absolutely fine in the player' the path is valid. I've since managed to fix it following a discussion with another developer. The problem was the order in which the texture and shader were update - they should have been the other way round. I'm not sure why it differs between the build and player however

Comment: I see. The reason that code work in the Editor is because the Editor remembers which Shader or Texture is assigned to a material. So, when you change the shader, it uses the old texture.

Comment: Appreciate the additional explanation - I'll add that to the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to locate any Unity documentation that explains why this scenario differed between Player and Build, however I was able to confirm that:

```
GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
 Renderer>().material.shader = shader;
```

Should have been declared in the opposite order:

```
Renderer>().material.shader = shader;
GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
```

Edit: Credit @Programmer 'The reason that code work in the Editor is because the Editor remembers which Shader or Texture is assigned to a material. So, when you change the shader, it uses the old texture'